# How to add user input box that will change path for the rest of the script in Linux

Tags: linux, user-controls

I am creating a script that requires directories to be changed contingent upon a subjects number, which is determined by the user. Instead of having a user manually edit the code, I want a box to pop up asking

`What is the subject number: emsint____FSL`

where the "____" is a number for the user to enter. Once this number is entered, I want it automatically changed throughout the rest of the code (i.e. every instance the ____ appears).

```
# Location of Subject
cd /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data
mkdir emsint____FSL

cd /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS_data_emsint____FSL
mkdir session1 session2

cd /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsint___FSL/session1 
mkdir control exper1 exper2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you asked for a popup box input, I don't think that is really needed, as you can keep all your user interaction at the keyboard (not requiring a mouse click).

If I understand your Q correctly, this should work for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "What is the subject number? "
read subNum

# Location of Subject
cd /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data
mkdir emsint"${subNum}"FSL

cd /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS_data_emsint"${subNum}"FSL
mkdir session1 session2

cd /mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data/emsint"${subNum}"FSL/session1
mkdir control exper1 exper2
```

There are other short-cuts and code-reductions that could be done here, most notably

```
#!/bin/bash
dataDir="/mnt/netshare/imaging/emoProc_MS_Intv_NMSS/data"

printf "What is the subject number? "
read subNum

# Location of Subject
cd "$dataDir"
mkdir emsint"${subNum}"FSL

cd "${dataDir}/emsint${subNum}FSL"
mkdir session1 session2

cd "${dataDir}/data/emsint${subNum}FSL/session1"
mkdir control exper1 exper2
```

IHTH